# Unable to Retrieve Staff Name from Firebase for Check-In/Check-Out Page

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am facing a new problem with fetching names from Firebase for the check-in/check-out page. I tried to pass it through from the login screen until the check-in/check-out page, but it is not working. Maybe this seems silly to you, but I genuinely do not know how to solve the problem.

Below, I have provided a snippet of my code.

staffdashboard:

```
 onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ManageFile(staffName: staffName,),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

managefile:

```
onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CheckInOut(
                          selectedFileName: fileName,
                          staffName: staffName, 
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

checkincheckout:

```
Future<void> saveCheckInOutTime() async {
  try {
    await checkInOutRef?.set({
      'fileName': widget.selectedFileName,
      'staffName': widget.staffName,
      'checkInTime': checkInTime != null ? Timestamp.fromDate(checkInTime!) : null,
      'checkOutTime': checkOutTime != null ? Timestamp.fromDate(checkOutTime!) : null,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error saving check-in/out time: $e');
  }
}
```

These three pages are included with:

```
final String staffName;

  ManageFile({required this.staffName});
```

I have successfully inserted the staff name into the staff collection in Firebase, but I am facing an issue in retrieving the staff name for the check-in/check-out page. Although I have managed to insert the filename, check-in time, and checkout time into the database, the staff name is not appearing as expected in the checkInOut collection. I need assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you.